# Want to debug SQL Server 2008 R2 stored procedure from VS2012 - Cannot see database in the SQL Server Object Explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

For the first time I am trying to debug a SQL Server 2008 R2 stored procedure being called by ASP.NET web app in Visual Studio 2012; application targets .NET framework 4.0.

I brought up the SQL Server Object Explorer for the first time. I see the system database, but there isn't even a node for the user databases. What am I missing? Hopefully there is a simple answer to this.

Comment: Make sure you open the right database. By default, it shows SQL Express.

Comment: I'll put that as an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you open the right database. By default, it shows SQL Express so if you use another database, you need to connect to it manually.